# Chunked transfer encoding

Tags: visual-c++, http.sys

i develop a Http server,
my Summary of response code is this:

```
PHTTP_DATA_CHUNK p = new HTTP_DATA_CHUNK[count];
for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
{
  p[i].DataChunkType = HttpDataChunkFromMemory;
  p[i].FromMemory.pBuffer = "dfdff"; 
  p[i].FromMemory.BufferLength = 5;
}

HTTP_RESPONSE response;  
ZeroMemory(&response,sizeof(HTTP_RESPONSE));  
PCSTR Reason="OK";  
response.StatusCode=200;  
response.pReason=Reason;  
response.ReasonLength=strlen(Reason);  
ADD_KNOWN_HEADER(response, HttpHeaderContentType, "text/html");
ADD_KNOWN_HEADER(response, HttpHeaderConnection, "keep-alive");
ADD_KNOWN_HEADER(response, HttpHeaderTransferEncoding, "chunked");
ADD_KNOWN_HEADER(response, HttpHeaderContentLength, chLen);

response.EntityChunkCount = count;
response.pEntityChunks=p;
ULONG BytesSent;
ULONG result = HttpSendHttpResponse(ReqQueueHandle, HttpRequest->RequestId, 
                                            0, &response, NULL,&BytesSent, NULL, 
                                            0,NULL,NULL, NULL);
```

But the result is `87`!
Now if I remove this line of code:

```
ADD_KNOWN_HEADER(response, HttpHeaderTransferEncoding, "chunked");
```

The result is `0` and my response is sent to client.
How I to make use of `Chunked transfer encoding`?

Comment: Error code: `87` is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`

Answer (score 1):

When I rearrange the code in the following way, the Response is send correctly:

```
response.EntityChunkCount = 0;
response.pEntityChunks=0;
ULONG BytesSent;
ULONG result = HttpSendHttpResponse(ReqQueueHandle, HttpRequest->requestId,
                                            0, &response, NULL,&BytesSent, NULL,
                                            0,NULL,NULL, NULL);
for (/*buffers */)
{
    PHTTP_DATA_CHUNK chunk;
    chunk.DataChunkType = HttpDataChunkFromMemory;
    chunk.FromMemory.pBuffer = buffer[i]; //--- "bufferLen\r\n .... \r\n"
    chunk.FromMemory.BufferLength = len[i];
    HttpSendResponseEntityBody(ReqQueueHandle, HttpRequest->requestId, 
                                 HTT_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_MORE_DATA, 1, &chunk, 0
                                 NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
}

PHTTP_DATA_CHUNK chunkEnd;
chunkEnd.DataChunkType = HttpDataChunkFromMemory;
chunkEnd.FromMemory.pBuffer = "\r\n0\r\n";
chunkEnd.FromMemory.BufferLength = 5;
HttpSendResponseEntityBody(ReqQueueHandle, HttpRequest->requestId,
                                 HTT_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_DISCONNECT, 1, &chunkEnd, 0
                                 NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```